# Changing Button Text With Random Number

Tags: android, button, textview

i've got this button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/headerButtonRestart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/view2"
    android:text="100" />
```

What I want is to change randomly the text with integers numbers between 1 and 100. So I did this:

```
        OnClickListener CienListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Random randd = new Random();
            int value=randd.nextInt(100)+1;
            TextView daucent = (TextView)(vf.findViewById(R.id.headerButtonRestart));
            daucent.setText(Integer.toString(value));
            }
    };

    Button d100 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.headerButtonRestart);
    d100.setOnClickListener(CienListener);
```

But it didn't work. Sorry I'm absolutelly beginner.

Comment: "didn't work" means what? I guess you got a class cast exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    d100 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.headerButtonRestart);
    d100.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             Random randd = new Random();
                int value=randd.nextInt(100)+1;
                d100.setText(""+value);
        }
    });
}
```

Hope this resolves your problem.